# Notifcation not showing on phone, but ok in emulator

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am running the Google GCM test code from [here](http://code.google.com/r/felipeal-gcm/source/browse#git/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm) and it runs on both emulator and phone, however when I do a send message the notification only works on the emulator and not the phone.

**GCMIntentService Notifcation**

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
...

// issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText(message);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // add notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(FM_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

**PHP Send message and send function**

```
require_once 'push_db_functions.php';
$dbf = new push_db_functions();
$id = '40';
$message = "Test Message";

$response = $dbf->sendMessage($id, $message);
$response = json_decode($response);
print_r($response);
```

---

```
public function sendMessage($id, $message) {
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT regid FROM test WHERE id = '$id'");
    $processed = mysql_fetch_row($results);
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $apiKey = "AIzaSyD-xxx";
    $fields = array('registration_ids' => $processed, 'data' => array( "message" => $message),);
    $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey, 'Content-Type: application/json');

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    // set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    // execute post
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

**Send message response**

```
stdClass Object ( [multicast_id] => 5036849453049739126 [success] => 1 [failure] => 0 [canonical_ids] => 0 [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message_id] => 0:1353799902066759%04108f12f9fd7ecd ) ) ) success
```

I have 2 regId records in my database, one for the emulator and one for the phone $id 39 and 40 and change them accordingly to send messages to either device.

**Database records**

```
id | regid
39 | APA91bFyMJx4b0ddI........ Emulator
40 | APA91bFhwEhHOClkg........ Phone
```

The phone is running Gingerbread and the program registers and runs correctly on it except for not displaying the notification upon message receipt.

```
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    Log.d("registrationID", "::" + regId);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // automatically registers application on startup.
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So an event is received showing that programmatically you receive the notification on the phone, you're just having trouble getting the actual notification to show in the notification bar?

Comment: Yes that is correct message received programmatically, but no notification showing in the notification bar

Comment: How do you call generateNotification ? What are the versions of emulator and device ?

Comment: Ooops, my previous comment maybe is incorrect, as I have just set a breakpoint in generateNotification and it never triggers on message sent

Comment: Device is running 2.6.35.7, emulator Google API's 16 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Comment: Message is received by GCMIntentService  @Override
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
  displayMessage(context, message);
  // notifies user
  generateNotification(context, message);
 }

Comment: I have also tested successfully on the 2.3.3 emulator and it works fine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone that responded to this question.

I have resolved the issue:

On my phone under Accounts & Sync, General sync settings, I found that the Background data sync box was not ticked. When set all works fine.

I should have figured this out before asking the question, my apologies.

However I hope this answer can be of assistance to others.